# How to decompose class dummy variable in panel model?

Tags: regression, econometrics, panel-data, finance

Maybe this is a question more of research design...

I am interested to research on analysts forecast ability (Dependent Variable) among two classes of analysts (1) Investment bank analysts (2) Non-IB Bank.

In a panel setting, I am able to prove that IB analysts has incremental value by using a dummy that is value of 1 if they are from investment bank and 0 otherwise.

Forecast Ability ~ DUMMY_IB + X + Controls..

Now i want to explain the source of outperformance by decomposing DUMMY_IB into a range of IB-specific attributes. May i ask what is the conventional way to do this ? Should i just use back the same regression but have these IB-specific attributes coded as Zero for non-IB analysts ?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Provided that IB analysts have at least one of those IB-specific attributes: You should use a new variable (dummy if binary) $A_i, i=1,\ldots, k$ for each of those additional IB-specific attributes, and they would all be set to zero for non-IB analysts. You would also have a common offset dummy that would be one for all of them.